# Spring JWTAuthenticationFilter returns a 403 but performs the request anyway

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I have been playing around with spring security and I've been trying to get a JWTAuthorizationFilter working for my requests, but whilst the filter does return a 403 forbidden for requests if the user is not logged in as expected, the request is still performed when it shouldn't be.

For example, if I have a method to create a new project, the project is created, and the server returns a 403 but the expected behaviour is a 403 and no project created.

I have been using https://github.com/devdojobr/springboot-essentials/blob/master/src/main/java/br/com/devdojo/config/JWTAuthenticationFilter.java as a reference but I still haven't had any luck.

My best guess is that it's an issue with the filter chain but I'm not too sure how this could be the problem

I've attached my Filter class and my SecurityConfig below:

Any help or pointers would be great.

JWTAuthorizationFilter.java

```
package uk.ac.qub.eeecs.csc3045.year1819.cs1.server.security;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import uk.ac.qub.eeecs.csc3045.year1819.cs1.server.service.SpringUserDetailService;

@Component
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

  @Value("${security.jwt.token.secret-key:secret-key}")
  private String secretKey = "secret-key";

  @Value("${security.jwt.token.expire-length:3600000}")
  private long validityInMilliseconds = 3600000;

  private final SpringUserDetailService springUserDetailService;

  public JWTAuthorizationFilter(
      AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, SpringUserDetailService springUserDetailService) {
    super(authenticationManager);
    this.springUserDetailService = springUserDetailService;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.doFilterInternal(request, response, chain);

    String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer "))  {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = getAuthenticationToken(request);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
    chain.doFilter(request,response);
  }

  private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthenticationToken(HttpServletRequest request)  {
    String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (token != null)  {
      //parse token
      String user = Jwts.parser()
          .setSigningKey(secretKey)
          .parseClaimsJws(token.replace("Bearer ", ""))
          .getBody()
          .getSubject();
      UserDetails userDetails = springUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(user);

      if (user != null) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
      }
        return null;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
package uk.ac.qub.eeecs.csc3045.year1819.cs1.server.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import uk.ac.qub.eeecs.csc3045.year1819.cs1.server.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter;
import uk.ac.qub.eeecs.csc3045.year1819.cs1.server.service.SpringUserDetailService;

/**
 * Configuration settings for management of JWT.
 *
 * JWT Implementation adapted from @see <a href="https://jwt.io/</a>
 */
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private SpringUserDetailService springUserDetailService;

  @Override
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  /**
   * Configure settings for JWT.
   *
   * @param http Spring security builder.
   * @throws Exception
   */
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/v2/users/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), springUserDetailService));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not continue filter chain execution when you dont find any `UserDetails`.
Try to throw an `AuthenticationException` and commence it through `AuthenticationEntryPoint`.

You can check exact behavior on [Spring Security JWT : JwtAuthorizationFilter](https://github.com/zainabed/zainabed-spring-security-jwt/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/zainabed/spring/security/jwt/filter/JwtAuthorizationFilter.java)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Zainul, throwing an exception and going through the AuthenticationEntryPoint got me the expected behaviour.